# HTML/CSS making column width 100%

Tags: html, css, dotnetnuke

I have this problem when I make columns using col-sm-12 and add a col-lg-3 and col-sm-9 inside the column of 12, when the col-lg-3 does not have content, col-sm-9 does not take 100% width of the container.

```
<hr style="border-color: darkgray;">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h4><a id="homeAnnTitle" href="[LINK]">[TITLE]</a></h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="homeAnnImg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 hidden-sm">[IMAGE]</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9" style="padding: 0 15px 0 15px;">
            [SUMMARY]
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div align="right">
            <button 
                style="
                width: 100px; 
                height: 35px; 
                border-radius: 5px;
                background-color: #e44726; 
                text-align: center;
                border: none;" 

                id="readMoreBtn" 
                type="button">
                    <a href="[LINK]" 
                        style="
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: white;">Read More ></a>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
<br>
```

How can I do it in such a way that if col-lg-3 has no content, col-sm-9 takes a 100% width?

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can create an script that verify if col-lg-3 dont have content, convert the col-sm-9 in col-sm-12 whit javascript. Im prog jr, and i dont know much of js, but i think that you can do it like that.
Your need, can do only whit an script.

Comment: I have thought about this way of doing it but im not very sure how to do it with js. Im not very familliar with js as well

Answer (score -1):

I agree with João Gonçalves!! however you could also convert it to 'w-100' to make the col width 100% of the page or use 'col-auto' to allow the page to automatically adjust itself. FYI be careful when using w-100 because it has a habit of behaving like a line break for tables but if there is content in the colunm it should be perfectly fine

Comment: I tried w-100 and col-auto as the class and it did not work. Am I doing something wrong?